# mysql LEFT JOINS does not work on the page

Tags: php, sql

**I have a problem with mysql joins. I wrote the join but in the page still prints only id.**

**//Here is my method where I wrote my SQL**

```
public function gameDiv() {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $stmt = $this->connect()->query("SELECT g.game_id, g.game_name, g.image_src, g.genre_id, g.developer_id, g.release_date, g.platfrom_id, g.game_price,  g.game_description, g.processor, g.graphic, g.ram FROM game AS g LEFT JOIN genre AS z ON g.genre_id = z.id WHERE game_id = '$id'");
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

I have two tables: 'game' and 'genre'. In table 'game' I have column 'genre_id' and in table genre i have column 'id' and 'name' And I made the relationship between 'game.genre_id' and 'column.id'.
I expect that instead of ID on the page display the name of genre from table genre. Right now, it only prins ID number from table game on column genre_id.

Comment: i think u also need to use alias for `WHERE game_id = '$id'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the genre table `z` to get the name. Notice the `z.name` in the query.

`$stmt = $this->connect()->query("SELECT g.game_id, z.name, g.game_name, g.image_src, g.genre_id, g.developer_id, g.release_date, g.platfrom_id, g.game_price,  g.game_description, g.processor, g.graphic, g.ram FROM game AS g LEFT JOIN genre AS z ON g.genre_id = z.id WHERE game_id = '$id'");`

I notice you are using the GET query directly in your query please look at [SQL Injection and properly use prepared statements](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md)

Comment: This should not be upvoted.  The correct solution is to use parameters.

Comment: Where exactly I need to notice 'z.name' in the query? Am I need to delete 'z.id' or write that next to 'z.id' ?

Comment: @Eris the z.name will print out the genre. So put that where you want, add remove the columns as you wish.